# Oracle RAC 19c instance fails to start with ORA-29707: inconsistent value 1 for initialization parameter 1146 with other instances

Tags: oracle, clustering, rac, failover-cluster-instance

After having to restart a node in a RAC cluster, we ran into "ORA-29707: inconsistent value 1 for initialization parameter 1146 with other instances" when trying to use srvctl start instance -i ORAPD3 -d ORAPD.

CMD output was something like:
PRCR-1013 : Failed to start resource ora.orapd.db
PRCR-1064 : Failed to start resource ora.orapd.db on node corprac03
CRS-5017: The resource action "ora.orapd.db start" encountered the following error:
ORA-29707: inconsistent value 1 for initialization parameter 1146 with other instances
. For details refer to "(:CLSN00107:)" in "/u01/app/grid/diag/crs/corprac03/crs/trace/crsd_oraagent_oracle.trc".

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find that the RAC instances somehow had gotten different configuration parameters. I could not find a lot on the ORA-29707 or the CRS-5017 errors that I could get access to.

To see what parameter the database was getting stuck on, I was able to use the following:
select * from v$parameter where num = 1146

That lead me to know the name of the parameter. In my case it was _lm_share_lock_opt.

To correct the issue, we were able to run the below on one of the other instances in the RAC cluster:
ALTER SYSTEM SET "_lm_share_lock_opt"=FALSE SCOPE=SPFILE SID='*';
This was ran on another instance where the database was still on-line. (Surviving instance)
Once the database instance came on-line, I restarted all the database instances in the cluster one at a time.

This can happen when an alter system is ran without the SID option on a RAC cluster.